# Evaluate $\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{\sin z}{z-\pi/2}\,\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

> **Problem.**<sup>[1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlJ6b.png)</sup> Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{\sin z}{z-\pi/2}\,\mathrm{d}z$, given that $\mathcal{C} : |z| = \pi/2$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: Also, please use MathJax to format your question. It greatly helps the question visible to various search engines and hence is crucial for maintaining this community as a repository of mathematical knowledge. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cauchy's integral formula.

$$\int_{|z|=a} \frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz = 2\pi i f(a) $$

For your question $f(z) = sin(z)$

So answer to your question is $2\pi i sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 2\pi i$

Comment: But the contour $C$ contains a discontinuous point $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: The Cauchy's integral formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula requires $a$ to be inside of the contour, not on the contour. Here the integrand is unbounded, so it is not integrable.

Comment: Yes, didn't noticed that. @J.D the answer is probably wrong.